# Formatting a control char for Word in python

Tags: python, mysql, ms-word

I need to use Python to read a MySQL table and print selected fields into a Word 2000 document that can be used to print labels in an Avery 6450 Round Labels template. When I enter the data manually I enter the following chars:
Note: /n is a carriage return and /t is a tab character.

## 123/n===/n$456/t/t

So, on the template in Word this looks like:
[image]

I tried using the /n & /t, but they print out literally, do not act as the control characters that I need.

I am using the following code:

```
        $Sq_record = '#'.$bowlID.'\n==='.'\n$'.$price;
        fwrite($Sqfile, $Sq_record);
        fwrite($Sqfile, "\t\t");
```

Comment: Does the language you're using have a way to specify ASCI/ANSI characters? \n is ANSI 13 and \t is ANSI 9. Word can/does recognize both.

Comment: After searching this morning I found that I had coded the control chars incorrectly - they need to be in double quotes in order to be seen as control chars...so $Sq_record = '#'.$bowlID."\n".'==='."\n".$'.$price; works. It still doesn't quite line up correctly, nut that should be easy to fix. Thanks.